# ASP.NET Core 2.0 connect to SQL Server 2000 error message "The SQL Server instance returned an invalid or unsupported protocol version"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core

Needed help here, So I am deploying my ASP.NET Core 2.0 into Windows Server IIS

All other pages load just fine,
But when it comes to the page that connect with the db to retrieve data, I will have error

```
"The SQL Server instance returned an invalid or unsupported protocol version"
```

I realise that the SQL Server that I am using is SQL Server 2000 and it is not supported by .NET Core 2.0

What should I do? Any workarounds? I couldnt upgrade the SQL Server at the moment.
Should I just use normal ASP.NET MVC ?

Thanks.

Edit: My appsetings

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnectionString": "Server=testserver;Database=testdb;Trusted_Connection=True;Integrated Security=SSPI"
  }
}
```

Comment: please add you `appSettings.json` in question

Comment: SQL server 2000 was reach the end of _extended_ lifecycle more then 5 years ago (April 9th; 2013)! You shoul upgrade it ASAP.

Comment: @ershoaib Thanks for your reply. Added the appsetings

Comment: @vasily.sib Thanks for ur reply. I understand that, but I dont have the rights at the moment and its gonna take time for the management to approve and at the moment I need to connect to the db

Comment: *I realise that the SQL Server that I am using is SQL Server 2000 and it is not supported by .NET Core 2.0* So run ASP.NET Core on the full framework?

Comment: Since you already know .NET Core doesn't support SQL Server 2000, and you are forced to reject the option to stop using SQL Server 2000, there's really not anything left but to not use .NET Core.

Comment: Your management is late for 5 years now - looks like they really "don't care at all", as for me. And if they don't care, why should you? My advise will be: "If its working - dont even touch it". EF Core support MSSQL 2008+ [as stated here](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/providers/), so it is not an option. And I'm not sure wich version of classic EF support SQL server 2000.

Comment: @vasily.sib Thank you very much. I think I should resort into MVC ASP.NET

Answer (score 2):

.NET Core does not support SQL Server versions lower than SQL Server 2005. Or rather, it does not support TDS protocol versions lower than TDS 7.2 (the version introduced by SQL Server 2005)

You will find more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45412345/the-sql-server-instance-returned-an-invalid-or-unsupported-protocol-version-duri)

Try to upgrade your SqlServer if its possible

Comment: @hvd, I added a link in answer that help her you just say its not supported but in answer i gives her the reason in link

Comment: In my solution i provide a link that can be helpful for her and she's find that what exact cause

Comment: Knowing the exact details of how and why it isn't supported doesn't help solve the problem. The question isn't "why doesn't this work", it's "how do I get this working".

Comment: @hvd, from the link in answer may gives her what she have to do and then she takes proper decision