# Where to download the old SQL ODBC driver version 10 (not the Native Client)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, odbc-sql-server-driver

We have a legacy application that fails to connect to SQL Server on certain computer (we have activated TLS, and that computer now raises an SSL error).

The problem is that the application is hard-coded to connect through the driver named "SQL Server", so my question is where can I download the latest installer of that old ODBC Driver ?.

[image: SQL Server driver]

I'm looking for the latest installer, because on my computer I have a more modern version of that driver and it runs correctly the legacy application that raises this error.

[image: SQL Server driver]

On the Microsoft site I've only found the more modern ODBC drivers for SQL Server (version 11 and upwards).

Comment: According to [Compatibility of ODBC driver SQLSRV32.dll with SQL Server versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50040188/compatibility-of-odbc-driver-sqlsrv32-dll-with-sql-server-versions), the driver comes with windows.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu. There is no installer available independently ?, That user runs on a terminal server 2016 that I wouldn't like to mess too much.

Comment: @MarcGuillot, correct, the drivers included with Windows are aligned with the OS version and cannot be installed separately. Not sure about ODBC but the SQLOLEDB driver included with Windows Server 2019 does support TLS 1.2 (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46011694/does-microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-support-tls-1-2)).

Comment: Thanks @DanGuzman, looks like we will need to have that legacy application updated (its connection string is hardcoded, so as of now it won't use the SQLOLEDB driver).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR**: You need to update that PC to a newer version of Windows 10. [According to Microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67944011/87698), the "SQL Server" ODBC driver included in Windows 10 Build 17763.1554 and later supports TLS 1.2.

---

**Details**: The legacy MDAC "SQL Server" driver comes bundled with Windows.

Note that the build numbers of the "SQL Server" ODBC driver in your screen shots exactly match the following [Windows 10 build numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history):

- 10.00.14393: Windows 10 1607 (Redstone 1)
- 10.00.19041: Windows 10 20H1

This does *not* mean that your PC uses that ancient version of Windows 10; it *seems* to be the lastest version in which that ODBC driver was updated (I use Windows 10 21H2 and the SQL Server ODBC driver still shows up as 10.00.19041).

Comment: Yes, that user runs on a Windows quite old (it's a Terminal Server 2016). I didn't realized that the driver was bundled with Windows. Looks like that we will need to find the original programmer so he updates that application to use a modern ODBC driver for SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Found this location. Maybe you can use this?

[SQL Server Native Client 10.0 ODBC Driver](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-10-0-odbc-driver/info-and-download/)

Update:
According to that page: The driver is included in the "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Feature Pack".

This is at:  [Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 4 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44277)

and the link to the service pack: [SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 4](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44278)

Comment: The "SQL Server Native Client" is a distinct driver with a distinct name. An application specifically asking for "SQL Server" will not get this driver. It's a bit unfortunate that there are now no less than three (at least) different "branches" of Microsoft-supplied ODBC drivers for SQL Server all vaguely containing "SQL Server", but there we are.

Comment: The links in that article, to the downloads, appear to also be broken.